# obiee server don't connect in centos

Tags: centos, virtualbox, obiee

after installing oracle bi in my virtual machine centos everything works good but after shutting down the machine , I cannot access the localhost.localdomain:9704 I think it cause the machine have changed the IP address can anyone help please .
the virtual machine is centos 5.4 in virtual box .

Comment: After reboot, are you starting the components needed?

Comment: no , how i can start that componets needed and what componets its

Comment: same issue   Patrick LC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After rebooting your machine, you have to start all components related to your OBIEE install. You have to handle:

1. Admin Server of your Weblogic domain.
2. Node Manager associated.
3. OBIEE Server (the managed server).
4. BI Componentes (opmnctl).

This steps are explained in detail in [Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/bi.1111/e10541/components.htm#BIESG3597).

You could also check a [script](https://community.oracle.com/message/9385047) on how to perform this tasks automatically, so you could add the service at Centos startup.

Comment: think you i will try now

Comment: Could you check in your weblogic console if the status of the OBIEE Server is started?

Comment: in the console there's many warning after that the server shuted down. Ignored deployment of role "Admin" for resource "type=<url>, application=DMS Application#11.1.1.1.0, contextPath=/dms, uri=/" and there is other

Comment: <Error> <org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.internal.AdapterManager> <BEA-000000> <ServletContainerAdapter manager not initialized correctly.>